Thingsboard Google Map Get Direction Action Doesn’t work properly
I’m currently trying to use the Thingsboard Live Demo dashboard in order to make my own GPS. My GPS sends information to Thingsboard fine, but the Google Map widget on the dashboard is an issue. The map successfully takes the information and places a pin there, but I added a mobile action (via the dashboard) that opens up the map directions.
By default, the code is like below:
// Function body that should return location as array of two numbers (latitude, longitude) for further processing by mobile action.
// Usually location can be obtained from entity attributes/telemetry. 

 return getLocationFromEntityAttributes();
// return [30, 30]; // TEST LOCATION


function getLocationFromEntityAttributes() {
    if (entityId) {
        return widgetContext.attributeService.getEntityAttributes(entityId, 'SERVER_SCOPE', ['longitude', 'latitude']).pipe(widgetContext.rxjs.map(function(attributeData) {
            var res = [0,0];
            if (attributeData && attributeData.length === 2) {
                res[0] = attributeData.filter(function (data) { return data.key === 'longitude'})[0].value;
                res[1] = attributeData.filter(function (data) { return data.key === 'latitude'})[0].value;
            }
            return res;
        }));
    } else {
        return [0,0];
    }
}

Yet it doesn’t work even if my datapoints are both called latitude and longitude.
I’ve tried changing names of the variables used in the function, searched up the function, and I haven’t found a solution. I’m new to using Thingsboard so I don’t really know which variables remain local or global.
